Secure WMTS service with GeoServer and authkey failing
I have an issue with serving a secure WMTS service with GeoServer (v2.25.2). I created the server and want to have different clients access imagery via AGOL and other places. I setup authkey authentication and tested on a WMS service. Works fine. However, I can't get secure WMTS to work but it works fine with no security on the same layer. Below is an example.

When I look at one of the 404 failures it gives the error message.
Unknown resource /MtArthurCoal_Quicklook_Ortho_20240517/gwc/service/wmts/rest

In my case the MtAr...17 is the layer name. I had a play with the filter chains to try and get this to work but with no success.
Any ideas?
